issue word document font size and font family is not proper according templates
Get doc file blob format and base64 string
let url = `${location.origin}/assets/templates/test.docx`;
 fetch(url).then(response => response.blob()).then((base64String) => {
      blobToBase64(base64String).then(async (res: any) => {
        let documentBase64 = res.split(',')[1];
        this.updateDocument(documentBase64 );
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });       
    }).catch(error =>  {
      console.log(error);
    })

Update document in Word Document
updateDocument(templateBase64) {
  Word.run(async context => {
     context.document.insertFileFromBase64(templateBase64, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
     await context.sync();
       
   })
}

expected: font size and font family according update document

document.insertFileFromBase64() API can import all styles when InsertOption param is setted. You can refer to this document and use it like this sample:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.document?view=word-js-preview#word-word-document-insertfilefrombase64-member(1)
context.document.insertFileFromBase64(externalDocument,"Start", {
  importTheme: true,
  importStyles: true,
  importParagraphSpacing: true,
  importPageColor: true,
  importChangeTrackingMode: true,
  importCustomProperties: true,
  importCustomXmlParts: true,
  importDifferentOddEvenPages: true
});

